Convert data Frame from long to wide in R
I would like to transform a long data frame (see example) below to a wide format.
My data structure looks something like this
| Month    | ID             |Tx    | F |
| -------- | -------------- |------|---|
| 12       | 1              | -0.1 |1|
| 12       | 1              |  -0.1|2|
| 24       | 1              | 0.1  |3|
| 60       | 1              |  -0.45|4|
| 12       | 2              | -0.34 |1|
| 12       | 2              |  0.123|2|
| 24       | 2              | 0.15 |3|
| 12       | 3              |  0.4|1|
| 12       | 3              | -0.153|2|
| 24       | 3              |  -0.5|3|

My code looks like this
pivot_wider(
  df.supine, 
  names_from = df.supine$Month,
  names_prefix="Month_", 
  values_from = df.supine$Tx
)

I get the following error:
Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Locations 60, 96, 60, …, 60, and 96 don't exist.
ℹ There are only 30 columns.
Backtrace:
 1. tidyr::pivot_wider(...)
 2. tidyr:::pivot_wider.data.frame(...)

How can I fix this error?
My guess is, that the problem is, that not all IDs have all Months.


How can I fix this error?


You only need the column names for names_from and values_from. (@Carl)

It's because pivot_wider is a tidyverse::dplyr function who requires tidy-select arguments. It's a worth reading.
This will most likely throw an error:
#> pivot_wider(
#    df.supine, 
     names_from = df.supine$Month,
#    names_prefix="Month_", 
     values_from = df.supine$Tx
#  )

Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Can't select columns past the end.
ℹ Locations 12, 12, 24, …, 12, and 12 don't exist.
ℹ There are only 4 columns.

But this works just fine even without prefixes:
> pivot_wider(
    df.supine, 
    names_from  = Month,
    values_from = Tx
  )

# A tibble: 9 × 5
     ID     F   `12`  `24`  `60`
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1 -0.1   NA    NA   
2     1     2 -0.1   NA    NA   
3     1     3 NA      0.1  NA   
# ℹ 6 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows  

names looks for column names. If you pass supine.df$Month, it will look for columns 12, 12, 24 and so on, not Month!
If you want to use am external vector as argument, you need a selection-helper like any_of or all_of:
my_col <- "Month"

> pivot_wider(
    df.supine, 
    names_from  = any_of(my_col),
    values_from = Tx
  )

# A tibble: 9 × 5
     ID     F   `12`  `24`  `60`
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1 -0.1   NA    NA   
2     1     2 -0.1   NA    NA   
3     1     3 NA      0.1  NA   
# ℹ 6 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Not having all combinations for ID-Month isn't a problem. You can fill the missing values with values_fill:
> pivot_wider(
    df.supine, 
    names_from  = any_of(my_col),
    values_from = Tx,
    values_fill = 0
  )

# A tibble: 9 × 5
     ID     F   `12`  `24`  `60`
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1 -0.1    0     0   
2     1     2 -0.1    0     0   
3     1     3  0      0.1   0  
# ℹ 6 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Check the documentation and you'll be fine.

I notice that, compared to Carl, you leave out the " around Month and Tx... Would this answer still work if there had been a vector called Month or Tx with values not intended for use in pivoting?

Hey @OlympusMons, check out the second example on @Carl's answer: Month is without " too. About your question, if I understood right, with selection-helper any_of you can have columns not present in the df. These will be ignored and there will be no errors. With all_of, on the other hand, all columns listed in my_col must be present on df. Note. you can pass multiple columns as arg to names_from and values_from.

Lets say Tx = "ID" was run before pivot_wider and Tx included in values_from without the quotes. This seemed ambiguous. But for Tx to mean ID in the pivot one would need to use any_of(Tx) or all_of(Tx) and this is what you refer to as using an external vector. Thank you.

"Lets say Tx = "ID" was run before" --> Do you mean mutate(Tx = ID)?

You only need the column names for names_from and values_from.
Did you want any special treatment of column F?
library(tidyverse)

df.supine <- tribble(
  ~Month, ~ID, ~Tx, ~F,
  12, 1, -0.1, 1,
  12, 1, -0.1, 2,
  24, 1, 0.1, 3,
  60, 1, -0.45, 4,
  12, 2, -0.34, 1,
  12, 2, 0.123, 2,
  24, 2, 0.15, 3,
  12, 3, 0.4, 1,
  12, 3, -0.153, 2,
  24, 3, -0.5, 3
)

pivot_wider(
  df.supine, 
  names_from = "Month",
  names_prefix = "Month_", 
  values_from = "Tx"
)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>       ID     F Month_12 Month_24 Month_60
#>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1     1   -0.1      NA       NA   
#>  2     1     2   -0.1      NA       NA   
#>  3     1     3   NA         0.1     NA   
#>  4     1     4   NA        NA       -0.45
#>  5     2     1   -0.34     NA       NA   
#>  6     2     2    0.123    NA       NA   
#>  7     2     3   NA         0.15    NA   
#>  8     3     1    0.4      NA       NA   
#>  9     3     2   -0.153    NA       NA   
#> 10     3     3   NA        -0.5     NA

Created on 2024-05-08 with reprex v2.1.0
If the ultimate intent is to get to, for example, only one row per ID, then you may need to summarise first with some function, e.g. sum, mean etc., as the sample dataframe has duplicate months per ID, for example:
# purely illustrative and dependent on intent
df.supine |> 
  summarise(across(c(Tx, F), sum), .by = c(Month, ID)) |> 
  pivot_wider(
  names_from = Month,
  names_glue = "Month_{Month}_{.value}",
  values_from = c(Tx, F)
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>      ID Month_12_Tx Month_24_Tx Month_60_Tx Month_12_F Month_24_F Month_60_F
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1      -0.2          0.1        -0.45          3          3          4
#> 2     2      -0.217        0.15       NA             3          3         NA
#> 3     3       0.247       -0.5        NA             3          3         NA

Created on 2024-05-08 with reprex v2.1.0
